# display returned array data from database without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made a Facebook style post and comment page where a user can post and make comments on the post.

My first problem is when I tried to make comments on the posts, the `postID` that was getting inserted into my database is the latest post, even if I comment on a different `postID`.

The next problem is what I want to achieve is that after commenting on a post, the comment will pop up on the comment section even if I don't refresh the page. I already tried searching for a possible solution but none of those fits what I'm trying to do.

Here is the code for my page:

**post.php**

```
<?php 

foreach ($post_model->getcomment($postid) as $value) {
    if($postid == $value['post_uid']){
        ?>
        <div id="mycomments" class="col-lg-12" style="background:#eff9c7;">
            <img src="./<?php echo $session_image?>" class="pull-left" style="border-radius:50%;margin-top:10px;" width="7%" height="7%" />
            <p style="margin-top:18px;line-height:15px;"><strong class="font-1" style="margin-left:10px;"><?php echo $session_fname.' '.$session_lname?></strong> <?php echo $value['pc_comment']?><br>
                <span class="" style="margin-left:10px;font-size:.9em;color:gray;"><abbr class="timeago" title="<?php echo $value['pc_datesend']?>"></abbr></span> 
            </p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>

<div class="col-lg-12" style="background:#eff9c7;">
    <!--    <img src="../img/icons/no-icon-available.png" class="pull-left" style="border-radius:50%;margin-top:10px;" width="7%" height="7%" />-->
    <input type="text" name="mycomment" id="mycomment" class="form-control pull-right" style="width:92%;margin-top:17px;" placeholder="Comments..." />
</div>
```

The following code will send my comment to my database:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[name="mycomment"]').on('keyup', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var comments = $(this).val();
    var sid = $("#sid").val();
    var ses_image = <?php echo json_encode($session_image); ?>;
    var ses_fname = <?php echo json_encode($session_fname); ?>;
    var ses_lname = <?php echo json_encode($session_lname); ?>;

    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        if(comments.length){
            $.ajax({
                url: "../controller/post_controller.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:{ 
                   "id":sid,
                   "comments":comments,
                   "image":ses_image,
                   "fname":ses_fname,
                   "lname":ses_lname
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(Object.keys(data).length);
                    comments = '';
                    $("#sid").val('');
                    $("#mycomments").append();  // i dont know what to put here
                }
            });

        else
            alert("Please write something in comment.");
        }

    });
});
```

and lastly this my function where i insert and select my data's:

```
class post {

    public $dbh;

    public function __construct(PDO $dbh){
        $this->dbh = &$dbh;
    }

    function comment($postuid,$uimage,$ufname,$ulname,$comment){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pcomment (post_uid,pc_uimage,pc_ufname,pc_ulname,pc_comment,pc_datesend) VALUES('$postuid','$uimage','$ufname','$ulname','$comment',NOW())";
        $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        var_dump($query);
        $result = ($query->execute()? true :false);
        return $result;
    }

    function getcomment($mmyid){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pcomment WHERE post_uid = '$mmyid'";
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array("0"));
        $active_data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $active_data;
    }
}
```

**controller.php**

```
if(session_id() == '' || !isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();
$session_id = $_SESSION['id'];
require_once('../model/dbconfig.php');
require_once('../model/post.php');
$database = new Database();
$conn = $database->getConnection();
$com = new post($conn);
$comments = ($_POST['comments']);
$uid = ($_POST['id']);
$pc_uimage = ($_SESSION['image']);
$pc_ufname = ($_SESSION['firstname']);
$pc_ulname = ($_SESSION['lastname']);

if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['comments']))
{
    $res = $com->comment($uid,$pc_uimage,$pc_ufname,$pc_ulname,$comments);
}

$res = $com->getcomment($uid);
echo json_encode($res);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe sounds like can be solved by using different technologies/approaches. For example, if your are posting AJAX requests to the server for post creation, you can just return the created post and update your page (using jQuery, vanilla JavaScript or whatever framework at hand). You might also want to have some sort of Server side push (web sockets, long polling, etc).

If your are interested in integrating real time notifications to your page, I'd start by taking a look to some services like [pusher.com](http://pusher.com) or [pubnub.com](http://pubnub.com). These services allow you to subscribe to events that are triggered from your server, so you could 'listen' to changes in posts you are interested in. You might, for example, create a channel server side to broadcast changes to your posts. Then, on the client, you can subscribe to
such channel and get easily notified when there is an update that should be displayed. This can be implemented in under 10 lines, so it's really worth it.

By the way. both services offer a free tier that are perfect for small to midsized projects. I myself have used them in production apps up to 10 thousand users without paying a dime, so they will probably be perfect for your case

Answer (score 0):

The ajax result to your request is JSON. So you need to recreate the HTML of your comment with your javascript array results. You can use jQuery to create HTML tags and append to your `#comments` div

Answer (score 0):

Just refresh div on post ajax success

```
jQuery("#your_div").load( refreshurl , function() {
    // do. stuff
});
```